# Procedure for rebooting server with Soft RAID mdadm

Tags: hard-drive, shutdown, raid, reboot, mdadm

I've just made a raid10 on my ubuntu 14.04 server, and i was wondering if there was any step too do if i would to shutdown/reboot my server.
It a Software RAID with mdadm.

Do i need to make a script to stop the array before shutdown?

Tks